# Тройка вопросов по CSS

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте я новичок в программировании хотелось бы разобраться со следующими вопросами, если можно то объясните как для ребенка на примере еды, машин, домов, чего угодно только, как можно проще ну или как получится. Вот вопросы:

**1) Для чего используется тег Content.** ( Везде написано что он нужен чтобы вставить текст который первоначально в тексте отсутствует.Но для чего нужно создавать новый тег чтобы в него что то написать,не легче ли просто открыть `div` в котором есть этот текст и там его редактировать.

**2)Что такое псевдоэлементы и для чего они нужны в принципе** (Опять та же песня,у нас есть псевдоэлементы `after`и `before`используется они вместе с тегом `content`но для чего добавлять слово или предложение перед нашим текстом если это можно сделать непосредственно в теге `div`.

**3)Какая разница между атрибутом `class` и `id`** (Возможно что то лучше использовать,а что то нет,свойства вроде как идентичные).

Возможно я еще не сталкивался с тем чтобы правильно это применять, но заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам бы просто загуглить, а то сейчас минусов отхватите))

Comment: Во-первых, в одном вопросе на сайте должен быть ровно один вопрос, а не три. Во-вторых, всё это описано в учебниках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень вкратце и не по теории:

1 и 2) - Псевдоэлементы `::before` и `::after` нужны для того, чтобы засунуть что-нибудь до или после элементов. Применяются только к парным тегам (это те, которые закрываются, например ). Св-во `content` в них (да и не только) применяется для того, чтобы всунуть в них что-нибудь, например текст (крайне не рекомендуется). Чаще всего такое используется тогда, когда у элемента есть, скажем 3 разные картинки в оформлении.

3) **id** - атрибут у элемента, имеющий почти максимальный вес при разборе css, должен быть только 1 на странице, современные требования <strike>криворуких</strike> разработчиков гласят, что id должен применяться только когда это нужно в JS (на самом деле, им просто лень следить за уникальностью). **class** служит для присвоения некоторых св-в к элементу, причем их можно вешать на разные элементы, дабы не плодить код, например:

```
.grey-text{ color:#252525; }

<p class="grey-text">Some text</p>
<span class="grey-text">Another some text</span>
```

Имеет вес, меньший чем **id**, но эта информация сейчас не столь важна.

Answer (score 2):

1) При использовании псевдоэлементов before и after может понядобиться вставить в них какой либо текст, например для блока с ценой можно добавить псевдоэлемент и вставить в него символ валюты.
2) Может пригодиться для оформления. Часто используют для кастомизации списков и других элементов у которых нет нужных сss свойств. Например можно добавить уголок к блоку коментария и многое другое.
3) id - уникальный идентификатор который используют для единичного экземпляра, обычно используют когда такой элемент 1, либо когда нужно что-нибудь делать с элементом средствами js
   class - можно прицепить хоть к 100000 элементов, используют для оформления нескольких и более идентичных элементов